# Problem with using a content present in a variable to call an api in python in linux server

Tags: python, linux, api, terminal, scripting

I currently want to run a python script on linux terminal (putty ssh server) ,the same python script executes perfectly on jupyter (windows) but does not on linux.

the error is that it fails to initiate the api call.

i tried all the 3 ways of concatenating the contents present in the variable into the link but it is not working but it works perfectly when the script is run on jupyter notebook(outside of the ssh server)

[image]

[image]

[image]

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import requests

with open ("/home/dpadmin/anifold/tzdata/in/tz1.txt", "r") as file:
    file_contents=file.read()

print(file_contents)

#url = f"https://www.timeapi.io/api/Time/current/zone?timeZone=%7Bfile_contents%7D"
#response = requests.get(url)

#url = "https://www.timeapi.io/api/Time/current/zone?timeZone=" + file_contents
#response = requests.get(url)

url = "https://www.timeapi.io/api/Time/current/zone?timeZone=%7B%7D".format(file_contents)
response = requests.get(url)

print(response.json())
```

When running `python3 tzauto.py` on linux

```
Africa/Juba

Invalid Timezone
```

Comment: It's the `%7B%7D`, change to `{}`

Comment: @WakemeUpNow I am sorry, i didn't get you there

Comment: `"https://www.timeapi.io/api/Time/current/zone?timeZone=%7B%7D".format(file_contents)` to `"https://www.timeapi.io/api/Time/current/zone?timeZone={}".format(file_contents)`